# Wordpress . In Mate Theme

Tags: wordpress

I have a question about how I can edit the space that let the theme "Mate" in wordpress, before the title.
The space is very high, and not load the images at top
So do you know how it can be edited, without touching the css file?

Comment: What do you mean by "Mate"? I would add CSS via the customizer if you don't want to add CSS directly to a file.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are talking about [this theme](https://wp-themes.com/mate/). Please make sure to include as much details when you post a question, so that we would be able to help you promptly.

To answer your question, that height is hardcoded in the CSS :

[image]

To reduce the size, you have to add a custom CSS with something like this:

```
.article-height-large {
    height: 280px;
}
```

If that doesn't override the height value, you could try adding the `!important` after the `280px`. If you are unsure where to add the custom CSS, you could try installing a plugin that will allow you to add Custom CSS (this will be easier).

I would also suggest looking at the theme's settings/options page as it might have an option to reduce the size than adding the custom CSS code. Am not sure though as I haven't used that theme before.